# Kibana not able to connect with ElasticSearch (Azure)

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-active-directory, kibana

Good day:

I've deployed ElasticStack on Azure (Kibana, ElasticSearch and LogStash). I'm trying to query against ElasticSearch from Kibana but, getting this error: `action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [kibana]`. I've went as far as to SSH into Kibana (on Azure) and change kibana.yml authentication user to `elastic` however, it is still throwing the error related to `kibana` user though I changed the user to `elastic`.

Comment: how have you deployed Elasticsearch on Azure?

Comment: @RussCam yes I have. I figured out the issue. For me to connect to ElasticSearch from Kibana, I have to enter the ElasticSearch username and password in Kibana to connect.

Comment: _how_ have you deployed it? When you say _connect to Elasticsearch from Kibana_, do you mean the credentials that Kibana process uses, or the credentials that _you_ enter in the login page?

Comment: @RussCam to enter into the Kibana dashboard, I need to enter a username and password. I usually enter the username and password soley used for Kibana, which was created during the Elastic Stack provision process on Azure. When I log into Kibana using the `kibana` user, I can't issues queries from Kibana to ElasticSearch (which caused the error message above). However, when I login using the `elastic` user through Kibana, then I can query ElasticSearch using Kibana.

Comment: The built-in `kibana` user has privileges limited to the operations needed for Kibana to interact with Elasticsearch. You typically want to set up other users and roles using the `elastic` user, then use those user accounts for access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect Kibana to ElasticSearch (with security enabled in ElasticSearch), you'll have to enter the ElasticSearch creds into Kibana login page to get access to ElasticSearch. This only happens in Azure using Elastic Stack.